# @Transactional drastically slows down Rest API

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-data

Service gets data from DB in constructor and store it in `HashMap` and then returns data from `HashMap`. Please take a look:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/scheduler/api")
@Transactional(readOnly = true, transactionManager = "cnmdbTm")
public class RestApiController {

    private final Set<String> cache;

    @Autowired
    public RestApiController(CNMDBFqdnRepository cnmdbRepository, CNMTSFqdnRepository cnmtsRepository) {
        cache = new HashSet<>();
        cache.addAll(getAllFqdn(cnmdbRepository.findAllFqdn()));
        cache.addAll(getAllFqdn(cnmtsRepository.findAllFqdn()));
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/fqdn", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<SchedulerRestDto> checkFqdn(@RequestBody List<SchedulerRestDto> queryList) throws ExecutionException {
        for (SchedulerRestDto item : queryList) {
            item.setFound(1);
            if (!cache.contains(item.getFqdn())) {
                item.setFound(0);
            }
        }
        return queryList;
    }

    private Set<String> getAllFqdn(List<String> fqdnList) {
        Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
        for (String fqdn : fqdnList) {
            result.add(fqdn);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

But I always get a result in about 2sec. I thought it's a bit slowly for 35K string which I got from DB.

I tried to find out where problem is. I store serialized `HashMap` to file and modified constructor to:

```
@Autowired
public RestApiController(CNMDBFqdnRepository cnmdbRepository, CNMTSFqdnRepository cnmtsRepository) {
    try (final InputStream fis = getResourceAsStream("cache-hashset.ser");
         final ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)) {
        cache = (Set<String>) ois.readObject();
    }
}
```

after that service returned result less than 100 ms.

I think it's related with DB but I don't know exactly how I can fix it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours of experiments I realized that the main cause is annotation @Transactional on the class.

When I moved this annotation on a method, service returned response quicker. In my final decision I moved this annotation to a another class. New constructor is

```
@Autowired
public RestApiController(FqdnService fqdnService, SqsService sqsService) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(fqdnService);
    cache = fqdnService.getCache();
}
```

Code is cleaner and there aren't any performance issues.